# Create object from string repesentation in C API

Tags: python, c, python-3.x

I am working on a system which is embedding a Python interpreter, and I need to construct a `PyObject*` given a string from the C API.

I have a `const char*` representing a dictionary, in the proper format for `eval()` to work properly from within Python, ie: `"{'bar': 42, 'baz': 50}"`.

Currently, this is being passed into Python as a `PyObject*` using the `Py_Unicode_` api (representing a string), so in my python interpreter, I can successfully write:

```
foo = eval(myObject.value)
print(foo['bar']) # prints 42
```

I would like to change this to automatically "eval" the `const char*` on the C side, and return a `PyObject*` representing a completed dictionary.  How do I go about converting this string into a dictionary in the C API?

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to use `ast.literal_eval` for this instead of `eval`? (It doesn't really affect the answer, but it's worth thinking about.)

Comment: @abarnert The strings being parsed are all under my control, so I don't think I need to do this - it'll always be a dictionary containing various values of float, int, bool, or (properly escaped) string values.

Comment: If it's always a dictionary containing float, int, bool, and string reprs, why _not_ use `literal_eval`? It's a little simpler, and you get a bit of validation for free.

Comment: @abarnert If the code is simpler, that's fine - I'm just trying to figure out how to handle this on the C API side of things, so the script only sees the dictionary.

Comment: Actually, I overstated things by saying it's simpler; `builtins` is just as easy to get at as `ast`, or maybe easier, and after that they're identical. Maybe that was just a knee-jerk reaction…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two basic ways to do this.

The first is to simply call `eval` the same way you do in Python. The only trick is that you need a handle to the `builtins` module, because you don't get that for free in the C API. There are a number of ways to do this, but one really easy way is to just import it:

```
/* or PyEval_GetBuiltins() if you know you're at the interpreter's top level */
PyObject *builtins = PyImport_ImportModule("builtins");
PyObject *eval = PyObject_GetAttrString(builtins, "eval");
PyObject *args = Py_BuildValue("(s)", expression_as_c_string);
PyObject *result = PyObject_Call(eval, args);
```

(This is untested code, and it at least leaks references, and doesn't check for NULL return if you want to handle exceptions on the C side… But it should be enough to get the idea across.)

One nice thing about this is that you can use `ast.literal_eval` in exactly the same way as `eval` (which means you get some free validation); just change `"builtins"` to `"ast"`, and `"eval"` to `"literal_eval"`. But the real win is that you're doing exactly what `eval` does in Python, which you already know is exactly what you wanted.

The alternative is to use the compilation APIs. At the really high level, you can just build  a Python statement out of `"foo = eval(%s)"` and [`PyRun_SimpleString`](http://docs.python.org/3/c-api/veryhigh.html#PyRun_SimpleString) it. Below that, use [`Py_CompileString`](http://docs.python.org/3/c-api/veryhigh.html#Py_CompileString) to parse and compile the expression (you can also parse and compile in separate steps, but that isn't useful here), then [`PyEval_EvalCode`](http://docs.python.org/3/c-api/veryhigh.html#PyEval_EvalCode) to evaluate it in the appropriate globals and locals. (If you're not tracking globals yourself, use the [interpreter-reflection APIs](http://docs.python.org/3/c-api/reflection.html) `PyEval_GetLocals` and `PyEval_GetGlobals`.) Note that I'm giving the super-simplified version of each function; often you want to use one of the sibling functions. But you can find them easily in the docs.

Comment: This almost has it - it looks like `eval` expects a tuple, so I have to wrap args in `PyTuple_Pack`, but otherwise, this works (+ adding the reference count handling).

Comment: On a side note - any reason you used `Py_BuildValue("s", ` vs `PyUnicode_FromString`?

Comment: @ReedCopsey: Sorry, that's a silly typo. I meant to do `"(s)"`, to build the `str` and then build the arg `tuple` out of that in one step, instead of having to first build the `str` and then the `tuple`. Good catch.

Comment: Nice - the BuildValue with `"(s)"` makes sense, and simplifies things.  Thanks for your help on this!

Comment: @eryksun: That option is already explained in the answer (although I used `PyRun_SimpleString`). If you just want to evaluate the string, it's simpler; if you want to be sure you're doing exactly the same thing as the Python function, call the Python function.